# Licensing a wrapper library

Tags: licensing, python, setup.py, bsl

For the current open source I'm working on I need to create a Python package (that I'll be using as dependency) that wrap an existing C++ library released using Boost license.

I'll be shipping this Python wrapper/package using pip, so I need to define a `setup.py` file.
`setup.py` should contain informations about author name, support email and licensing.

What should I report as author and licensing in `setup.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your redistribution combines Boost-licensed code and your own source code in one source or binary package you will need to provide licensing for both. In the simpler case where you would elect to license your own code to be using the Boost license, then there is only one license and possibly multiple copyright statements. You can add these alright in the `setup.py` `license` metadata field. A great practice would be to use [SPDX license identifiers](https://spdx.org/licenses/) (if needed as a [license expression](http://wiki.spdx.org/view/LicenseExpressionFAQ) if you use more than one license) for the `license` field. You can also add a proper license classifier in the `classifiers` list field of your `setup.py` if there [is one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers) that applies well ... But I could not find a Boost license classifier even though this is an `License :: OSI Approved` license...

And typically you would also add a `LICENSE` file at the root for clarity, ensuring that it is included in the build source package with a proper entry in the `MANIFEST.in` file.

If you plan to also ship pre-built wheels you should also consider creating a `setup.cfg` with these lines to ensure that your `LICENSE` file is also included in the built wheels:

`[metadata]
license_file = LICENSE`

From a `setup.py` point of view, if you are clearly the author of the wrapper then you should add yourself in the `author` field. If you are merely packaging the C++ code without much of new code addition you could be the `maintainer` and the original author the `author`. Your call.